# Unallocated space does not come under /dev, thus can't use in other partitions

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have some unallocated space right adjacent to my Ubuntu root partition which I wanted it to extend into. I ran a live Ubuntu from USB and tried to expand the root using Gparted, but realized it didn't let me extend the memory bar.

I have a feeling this has something to do with the fact that my unallocated space does not come under `/dev/sda6`, (or any other `/dev/` either).
Please check screenshot

What can I do to fix this problem?

[image: Click for screenshot]

Comment: Complementing the answer below, your root (sda6) is a logical partition residing inside and extended partition (sda4) so you need to resize sda4 first and only then resize sda6 inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the unallocated space to the extended partition `sda4` and apply changes first.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so how I solved this-
1.Swapoff
2.Resized sda4 (as mentioned by a user) and filled the unallocated space
3.then from the live cd extended sda6

Thanks to everyone who helped! :)